# Why can SafeDisc disks be read faster if the game was opened before?

Tags: cd-rom, copy-protection

First of all I want to say I have the games in real and I am just making safety backups. The disks are old and tend to lose data.
I am using Alcohol 120 Retro edition and found something weird.
I have games disks that produce read errors when dumping. That is normal and part of the copy protection.
But it was very slow and I calculated it would take 2 days to dump 1 CD. The game was not installed.
So I did some search and found [this](https://forum.alcohol-soft.com/index.php?/topic/27683-slow-recording-of-game-disk/) post at the Alcohol 120 forum.
They say it's SafeDisc protection and if you open the game (then close it) before dumping it will dump faster. And it really helped!
But how can installing and opening the game increase CD read speed?
I cannot see the logic connection.

I posted this on retrocomputing because today all games are downloaded and no longer on disks. Hope that was right...

Comment: Just a wild guess: The CD driver might have a global state that tells the driver how to deal with read errors (e.g. the number of retries), and the amount of read-ahead (telling the drive to read 16 sectors even if the application only requested one sector, hoping that the extra sectors will be requested soon). These settings can have a huge performance influence on how fast CDs with intentionally bad sectors can be read. It's plausible that the SafeDisc code in the game changes these global settings.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher Can you name these settings and a tool to get and set them?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the internals of the Windows CD driver and CD drive configuration (SCSI mode pages accessible via ATAPI) well enough to name anything there.

Comment: @somega It would defeat the whole point of DRM if such tools were easily available…

Comment: @user3840170 Whole point? I think "this disc must be a copy. It has no genuine bad sectors on it." is a more significant facet to how things work. As a kid, I had no problem leaving a disc to copy overnight with something like a pirated copy of CloneCD.

Comment: There is hdparm, sdparm and setcd on Linux. Maybe these can set/get such values.

Comment: @ssokolow Yes, the whole point of DRM is that the end-user should have no ability to control how it operates, never mind understand it. The specific mechanism of distinguishing ‘genuine’ media is secondary to that. After all, if you knew the exact pattern of bad sectors the DRM system is looking for, you could write a CD driver that pretends the pattern is there, and tell everyone to install your driver when running software from a ‘counterfeit’ disc. (Which is more-or-less how PlayStation modchips work.) Why would there be any publicly-released tools? The point is to be opaque!

Comment: @user3840170 ...but it sounds like the tunables in question would be part of the standard, OS-provided ATAPI driver.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add a rough comparison of the two different timings? The uninstalled time, you say, seems to be around two days, but how much quicker is it once installed? You don't seem to say, you just say that it really helped.

Comment: @Greenonline Not installing makes CD reading faster but starting the game. Unfortunately I cannot remember anything about this case.

Answer (score 1):

I could help better if you mention the time difference between the two cases.

Perhaps Alcohol 120 Retro makes use of block caching done by MS Windows. What happens if you eject the CD, then re-insert it and try again to copy it? If it's slow (the original speed) after eject/insert, then block caching is likely the cause of the improvement.

Or perhaps installing the game also installs a driver. To check, try the following:

- clean boot of system (without game installed)
- install game, but don't run it
- check copying time
- reboot system (in case the possible driver only loads at boot time)
- don't run the game, then check copying time

If it's faster after installation but without running the game, there may be a driver involved and you can narrow your search.

Lastly, for the actual goal (having a useful backup of SafeDisc media), you may want to look into how to emulate bad blocks on a block device. Perhaps some CD emulator package has that feature.

Comment: +1 - for the interesting diagnostic steps. This is (now, since your edits) a nice answer.

Comment: Alcohol 120% (or the non-burning side of it, available separately as Alcohol 52%) includes a CD emulator but I can't remember if SafeDisc's bad sectors are consistent enough to be emulated without just recording where they were encountered in the disc image and and replaying that... which Alcohol's image format does support. CDEmu for Linux also supports mounting Alcohol dumps and doing bad sector emulation.